# Pass modifiable 2d array as class parameter

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm creating a 2d array to pass as a class parameter, i want to then make some changes to that matrix. i want to write something like this:

```
    //i found this randomly looking
    float **array;
    array = new float *[10];

    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
        array[i] = new float[10];

    //somehow create the matrix array

    point v1(0.6,0.9,1);
    point v2(0.3,0.9,1);
    point v3(0.5,0.4,1);

    // somehow pass array to class pipeline
    pipeline pipeline(array,10,10,1,2,1,-1);
    // i use a method in the class to modify the matrix array
    pipeline.computetriangle(v1,v2,v3);

    //print the matrix array
```

I assume i need to use pointers because the class pipeline needs to function with every possible size x,y of array[x][y]. I tried looking at similar question and found a dozen ways to do it that don't work for me, so here's my particular case. I would appreciate knowing how to use the array inside the class. Apologies if it's a noob question but i'm new to c++ and pointers in general.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mcve]. I don't see any "2d array" in your code.

Comment: With that said, remember that arrays naturally decay to pointers to their first element. So chances are you don't need to do much to be able to modify the contents of all the arrays.

Comment: i edited it, but that's precisely what i'm asking for, i don't know how to create such an array and be able to print it.

Comment: Now you have to be more specific with the whole "modifiable" bit. Are you supposed to modify any of the *pointers*? Or just the *data*? If just the data, pass it as the same type as `array`, i.e. `float**`.

Comment: alright, let's move away from the modifiable bit, just imagine i want to print array as it is written in my code, how do i do it?

Comment: The same, just pass a `float**` argument and display it like you would `array` directly.

Comment: To print it, you just do something like this: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) { std::cout << array[i][j] <<  ' '; } std::cout << std::endl; }`